# How to mentioned Required and Optional Parameters in GCP Dataflow Template?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have created a custom Dataflow Template that uses a few mandatory and optional parameters. I am able to create a Template but when I open it in **Dataflow UI**, it does not show my declared required parameters.

I got one annotation `@Validation.Required` but that is also not working. Is there anything I am missing?

**My Options Class is**

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Validation;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;

public interface TestOptions extends GcpOptions {
    @Description("Project Id")
    @Default.String("Project Id")
    ValueProvider<String> getProjectId();
    void setProjectId(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Validation.Required
    @Description("Path to the input file")
    @Default.String("gs://nikhil-test-bucket/Test/input.txt")
    ValueProvider<String> getInputFile();
    void setInputFile(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Validation.Required
    @Description("Path to the output file")
    @Default.String("gs://nikhil-test-bucket/Test/output.txt")
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputFile();
    void setOutputFile(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("Path to the Config file")
    @Default.String("gs://nikhil-test-bucket/Test/config.txt")
    ValueProvider<String> getConfigFile();
    void setConfigFile(ValueProvider<String> value);
}
```

Comment: Only the required fields are not visibles in the UI ? For example do you see the `configFile` option ?

Comment: no, all fields are part of additional parameters that need to pass as key and value where the key is name of the parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dataflow UI reads the `_metadata` file (also called spec) for the list of parameters, not the actual source code.

In the metadata parameter, you can specify `"isOptional": true` for any parameter.

Comment: Thanks, Now it is showing. Is there any way that when we are creating a custom template it can automatically move the _metadata file we are maintaining in the source code?

Comment: In the repository https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates we have some work to generate the _metadata file based on annotations, but it requires an extra set of annotations (see: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates#metadata-annotations).